# How to insert items into inherited table in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

i've created the table "employe" and "medecin" with all types needed,
like this:

"medecin" table inherits from "employe" table

```py
create type temploye as object( NUM_EMP Number(7),
                                NOM_EMP varchar2(30),
                                PRENOM_EMP varchar2(30),
                                ADRESSE_EMP varchar2(100),
                                TEL_EMP varchar2(10)
                                ) not final;
/

create type tmedecin under temploye( NUM_MED number(7),
                                     SPECIALITE varchar2(40),
                                     medecin_soigne t_set_ref_soigne,
                                     directeur_service t_set_ref_service
                                )not final;
/

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYE of temploye (NUM_EMP primary key);
/

-- Table MEDECIN 
create table MEDECIN of tmedecin
(
    constraint pk_NUM_MED primary key(NUM_MED),
    SPECIALITE check(SPECIALITE IN ('Anesthésiste','Cardiologue','Généraliste','Orthopédiste'))
)
nested table medecin_soigne store as table_medecin_soigne,
nested table directeur_service store as table_directeur_service;
/
```

**is there a way to insert elements in the "medecin" table without adding the attributes of "employe"**, I had an error when i did it, it says i need to specify all arguments.
i did something like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYE VALUES (temploye(4,'BOUROUBI','Taous','Lotissement Dauphin n°30 DRARIA/ALGER','021356085'));

INSERT INTO MEDECIN VALUES (tmedecin(4, 
'Orthopédiste', T_SET_REF_SOIGNE(), T_SET_REF_SERVICE ()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `create type tmedecin under temploye` so a `tmedecin` has all the attributes of the parent type `temploye` as well as the extra attributes defined in the sub-type.

If you want to pass in a `tmedecin` type then you need to declare all the attributes:

```sql
INSERT INTO MEDECIN VALUES (
  tmedecin(
    4,
    'NOM',
    'PRENOM',
    'ADRESSE',
    'TEL',
    4, 
    'Orthopédiste',
    T_SET_REF_SOIGNE(),
    T_SET_REF_SERVICE ()
  )
);
```

But you could declare them as `NULL`:

```sql
INSERT INTO MEDECIN VALUES (
  tmedecin(
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    5, 
    'Orthopédiste',
    T_SET_REF_SOIGNE(),
    T_SET_REF_SERVICE ()
  )
);
```

Or, you could use `INSERT` and name the columns rather than passing in a `TYPE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO MEDECIN (
  NUM_MED,
  SPECIALITE,
  medecin_soigne,
  directeur_service
) VALUES (
  6, 
  'Orthopédiste',
  T_SET_REF_SOIGNE(),
  T_SET_REF_SERVICE ()
);
```

(Which will implicitly create the other columns with the default value, which unless otherwise specified would be `NULL`.)

---

#### However

You do not need the `MEDECIN` table as you could insert `tmedecin` types into the `EMPLOYEE` table:

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYE VALUES (
  tmedecin(
    5,
    'NOM',
    'PRENOM',
    'ADRESSE',
    'TEL',
    5, 
    'Orthopédiste',
    T_SET_REF_SOIGNE(),
    T_SET_REF_SERVICE ()
  )
);
```

And can even create similar constraints using:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employe ADD CONSTRAINT employe__spceialite__chk CHECK (
  OBJECT_VALUE IS NOT OF (tmedecin)
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS tmedecin).SPECIALITE = 'Anesthésiste'
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS tmedecin).SPECIALITE = 'Cardiologue'
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS tmedecin).SPECIALITE = 'Généraliste'
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS tmedecin).SPECIALITE = 'Orthopédiste'
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_uk1 ON employe(
  TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS tmedecin).NUM_MED
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0eaf308beac454e2a9c811e3fdd29cd)*

Comment: thank you for your explanation!

Comment: is there a way i can access "employe" through "medecin" table, when num_emp=num_med?

Comment: @NoviceBL Personally, I would not have two separate tables and would just put the `medecin` sub-types into the `EMPLOYE` table and then use the `TREAT` function to get the extra columns of the sub-type as necessary. There is an example of getting the sub-type's columns at the end of the db<>fiddle linked in the answer.

Comment: Otherwise, just use a `JOIN` in a query.